# How to use Core Graphics Layer Drawing

Tags: iphone, core-graphics, calayer

Can anyone tell me about how to color with pattern(Butterfly) like follwing link [a link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_layers/dq_layers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH219-TPXREF101).

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you want to achieve? The very link you posted tells you exactly how to use the CGLayer to accomplish drawing images like the butterfly pattern, that's *why* it's shown there.

Comment: I want to paint like brush using pattern and Pattern may be butterfly,star etc .You can see in free app [link](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/paint-gallery/id445258482?mt=8) use of brush and pattern.

Comment: I downloaded and played with the app. I understand exactly what you want to do but your question is very broad, there are any number of ways that functionality could be implemented. At best I could provide a series a links for you to begin researching how to undergo a similar project but the main one would be that which you included in your own question.

Comment: So can you provide some links? I am just want to pattern like Paint Gallary.

Comment: Is your Google broken?

Comment: You could try UIColor's colorWithPatternImage: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206207/how-to-cascade-image-pattern-in-uiimageview

Comment: Yes @Matt-Long  I try it But it fill the UIView not color like pattern.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to reading the entirety of the [CGLayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGLayer/Reference/reference.html) reference you posted in your original question I strongly advise you to watch the '[Optimizing 2D Graphics and Animation Performance](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/)' session from the 2012 WWDC.

As you progress I think you'll find that it isn't particularly difficult to draw content to the screen using the likes of [Quartz 2D](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html) and [Core Animation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) but the real challenge will be doing so in a way that achieves an acceptable level of performance.

In the session they optimise a drawing app similar to the one you want to create. The fundamental principals they used to optimize their drawing app were:

- Only ever update as little of the screen as you need to
- Every so often create a flat composite image of what the user has drawn and re-use this image in proceeding drawing operations. This prevents having to draw everything the user has drawn to the canvas individually, making the application much more performant.

In addition to this they cover a collection of tricks to squeeze out every drop of performance.

I apologise that I have no code examples for you (I usually like my answers to include some) but your question was very broad. I suggest you watch the video I have suggested, continue your research and attempt to begin implementing the application yourself. Once you run into more specific problems you can return here for answers in the event you can't find them elsewhere.

Good luck!

Comment: @iphoneProfile Was any of this of any help to you? It really was quite hard to help you achieve what you wanted based on the amount of information you provided in your original question. If you still haven't managed to accomplish what you want you could expand your question with specifics based on what you've learnt since. This would help myself and others give you more information.